# Number validation tailing . (Dot)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, validation

```
<input type="number" name="PortNumber" data-ng-model="Data.PortNumber" min="0" maxlength="5" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,6}$/">
<span ng-show="myForm.PortNumber.$touched && myForm.PortNumber.$invalid && myForm.PortNumber.$error.pattern">Invalid Port</span>
```

When I enter suppose 123. then it doesn't show any error message. But if i enter 123.1 or any other number after . then it shows the error message. How Can i show error at the case of 123.

Comment: Since your input type is *number*, the regex validation will not work, switch to `text`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You expression is matching any digit that is between 1 and 6 digits long. So of course it's going to match 123 since that falls between 1 and 6 digits.

Comment: I want to show the user an error message "You can't enter Dot (.) at the end."
No issue with float.

Comment: Did you try using `type="text"`?

Comment: Regex is working with number type and I need this field to be type='number'. Just could not give a case for tailing dot (.)